# if $string found break else add new not working

Tags: php, post

I am doing something wrong?
This doesn't take any effects

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$tudof = "\n #QTP ".$qtp." ID: ".$id;
echo "\n";
$fp = fopen('../../../ids.txt', 'a+');
$searchString = "id";

if(exec('grep '.escapeshellarg($searchString).' '.$fp)) {
    break;
} else {
    // Add the new name
    fwrite($fp, $writef);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

How to search a string and if not found add a new name?

Comment: **Beware**: Using `exec()` can be very dangerous if you don't know what you're doing! You should avoid it at all cost. Also, you can't break if not in a loop, which this doesn't seem to be. Just do one condition, check if the condition is not met and write, else do nothing?

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? Are you getting any errors? What is happening? What would you expect to happen? Did you check your error logs? Where is `$writef` defined?

Comment: `$fp` is a file handle not the contents.  Try `file_get_contents()`

Comment: What is `$tudof` supposed to do? You create the string but then don't use it. Also why not use a more conventional method with strpos, preg_match or preg_grep?

Comment: @Andreas tudof = writef It was a mistake, sorry! Can you answer my question with an example how to use strpos to search a string and if not found write?

Comment: @Mike Nothing happens... no errors, I need avoid doubled registers In a ID txt file. I was expecting that when the string $id (get via post) is not found write the ID. If found, does nothing

Comment: @Qirel Thank you for alert, that is exactly what I was trying to do... I am searching the right way to do that. You can show me an example? so I can learn and adapt for me, in my attempts I still can not make it work

Comment: @JuniorDavi Don't reinvent the wheel, especially since there are many things that can and will mess this up, like race conditions and file locking, which you're not accounting for. Use a real database. If you want to use files, go with sqlite. Or go with MySQL or PostgreSQL if you want a full-featured open-source RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work.
I use file_get_contents to load the file as one string and use strpos to find "id".
I also include a preg_match version since strpos will match "lid" for "id" which preg_match won't.

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$tudof = "\n #QTP ".$qtp." ID: ".$id;
echo "\n";
$str = file_get_contents('../../../ids.txt');
$searchString = "id";

if(strpos($str, $searchString) !==false) {
// Found it! Break won't work.
// If you want to stop all php code use exit; 
} else {
// Add the new name
// Not sure what you do here but use file_put_contents
file_put_contents('../../../ids.txt', $str);
}


// Preg_match
if(preg_match("/\b " . $str ."\b/", $searchString)) {
```